# Javascript function for a php loop

Tags: javascript, php, getelementbyid

I have this situation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("commentDIV");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

and the php code

```
<?php
echo "<table><tr  onclick='myFunction()'><td>Row A1</td></tr>"; //A1 row from my table
echo "<tr><td><div id='commentDIV' style='display:none'> Row B1</div></td></tr></table>"; // the B1 row show after click on the A1
?>
```

Everything works fine, when I click on the first row, the second appearance.

How can I use/modify my javascript function in this situation?

```
<?php
    $x=0;
    while($x<10){
        echo "<table><tr  onclick='myFunction()'><td>Row A$x</td></tr>"; //Ax row from my table
        echo "<tr><td><div id='commentDIV' style='display:none'> Row B$x</div></td></tr></table>"; // the Bx row must show after click on the Ax
        $x++;
    }
?>
```

Please help and save my day!
Many thanks!

Comment: Well for one, `id` must be unique across the entire DOM (html document). So that affects how you setup a click handler and modify elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` attribute should be unique at the document, try to change the duplicate ones by common classes like :

```
<?php
    $x=0;
    while($x<10){
        echo "<table><tr  onclick='myFunction(this)'><td>Row A$x</td></tr>"; //Ax row from my table
        echo "<tr><td><div class='commentDIV' style='display:none'> Row B$x</div></td></tr></table>"; // the Bx row must show after click on the Ax
        $x++;
    }
?>
```

**NOTE:** You should pass the 'this' object as an argument to your function.

Then in your js, you could use the passed argument to search for the related `div` using the class name `self.nextElementSibling.querySelector(".commentDIV")` and finally toggle the display like :

```js
function myFunction(self) {
  var related_div = self.nextElementSibling.querySelector(".commentDIV");

  related_div.style.display = (related_div.style.display === 'none') ? 'block' : 'none'
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr onclick='myFunction(this)'>
    <td>Row A1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class='commentDIV' style='display:none'> Row B1</div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr onclick='myFunction(this)'>
    <td>Row A2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class='commentDIV' style='display:none'> Row B2</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @stanciu-florică try this

Comment: Good job, Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using the same id "commentDIV" for all Divs so you should change the loop and function.

1. Add `$x` to div `id` originally known as `commentDIV`
2. Change the `myFunction` call to include the `$x` number
3. Add the id argument to the `myFunction` definition
4. Append the passed id to the `getElementById` value

Like this:

```
<?php 
$x=0;
while($x<10){
  echo "<table><tr  onclick='myFunction($x)'><td>Row A$x</td></tr>";
  //                                    ^^--- 2. add $x
  echo "<tr><td><div id='commentDIV_$x' style='display:none'> Row B$x</div></td></tr></table>";
  //                               ^^^--- 1. add $x
$x++;}
?>
```

The javascript code changes to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(id) {
         //             ^^--- 3. add id
         var x = document.getElementById("commentDIV_" + id);
         //                                         ^ ^^^^^--- 4. append id
         if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
         } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
         }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, IDs need to be unique to function properly, so I would rather use classes.

As stated, this table will be echoed 10 times:

```
<table>
  <tr onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <td>Row A$x</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="commentDIV" style="display:none">Row B$x</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Next, modify the javascript such that the element gets passed as a parameter, then get the first child of the next element:

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var x = e.nextElementSibling.children[0];
  if (x.style.display == "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: `.children[0]` isn't a good idea, if the column content change, the function will fail

Comment: Would `e.nextElementSibling.children[0];` actually choose the correct tr -> td-> div? I'm actually twisting my brain to visualize that selector. I admit though, I'm spoiled rotten by jquery at this point =p